# ConnectionRefusedError is raised when trying to run a program

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I built a chat room with python so that I can talk to my friends a different way but for some reason, my friend is getting a ConnectionRefusedError. I have a server.py file and a client.py file. The client.py files are the exact same, however my friend is the only one getting the error but not me. I don't know where I'm making a mistake so here's the code for both files:

**server.py**

```
import threading
import socket

host = "127.0.0.1" #localhost
port = 48812

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((host, port))
server.listen()

clients = []
nicknames = []

def broadcast(message):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(message)

def handle(client):
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024)
            broadcast(message)

        except:
            index = clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            nickname = nicknames[index]
            broadcast(f"{nickname} left the chat".encode('ascii'))
            nicknames.remove(nickname)
            break
def receive():
    while True:
        client, address = server.accept()
        print(f"Connected with{str(address)}")

        client.send("NICK".encode("ascii"))
        nickname = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
        nicknames.append(nickname)
        clients.append(client)

        print(f"Nickname of client is {nickname}\n")
        broadcast(f'{nickname}joined the chat!\n'.encode('ascii'))
        client.send("Connected to the server!\n".encode('ascii'))

        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client,))
        thread.start()


print("Server is listening...")
receive()
```

**client.py**

```
import socket
import threading

nickname = input("Choose a nickname: ")

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("127.0.0.1", 48812))

def receive():
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
            if message == 'NICK':
                pass
            else:
                print(message)

        except:
            print("An error occurred!")
            client.close()
            break


def write():
    while True:
        message = f'{nickname}: {input("")}'
        client.send(message.encode('ascii'))


receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive)
receive_thread.start()

write_thread = threading.Thread(target=write)
write_thread.start()
```

We were connected to the same wifi so I thought that it should work. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the localhost, i.e. your own computer. So you can run the server and client on the same computer, but you can't connect to the server from a different computer. Even though you're on the same wifi, you still have different IP-addresses. You might have the same **global** IP-address (i.e. the address to the router), but within the network of the router, each device will have a unique **private** IP-address.

Comment: So how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP-address `127.0.0.1` is the localhost (or "loopback" address), which is the address to your own computer. With it you can run the server and client on the same computer, but you can't connect to the server from a different computer.

Even though you're on the same WiFi, you still have different IP-addresses. Each device that connects to the internet needs an IP-address that doesn't conflict with other addresses. Basically, a router is connected to the "big" internet with a **public** IP-address and can talk with other devices around the world. Then you have a "small" internet on your side of the router where your computer, phone, smart-TV, etc. is connected. These all have **private** addresses, i.e. addresses that are only unique within the network of the router.

For your server to work, it needs to listen to all IP-addresses (or the client's **private** IP-address, which most likely is something like `192.168.1.X` where X is some number). You can listen to all addresses by binding to `0.0.0.0`

For your client to work, you need to connect to the server's **private** IP-address.

How to find it depends on your OS, but it's usually in the system settings or preferences. If you have Mac OS, then you can click on the WiFi icon while holding down the alt-key.